# I need react multi-select with virtualized list options

Tags: react-select, react-virtualized

I have a multi-select component with a lot of option data that takes a long time to load.

I optimized it with the [react-select-virtualized](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-virtualized) and
it works ok but it doesn't support multi-selection yet.

[image]Taken from: (https://github.com/guiyep/react-select-virtualized#what-we-do-support-and-dont-from-react-select)

I want a virtualized-selectbox with multiple value select options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below `stackblitz` app. It's very helpful for my requirement.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-v2-virtualized

In this app, They create a `react-select` component with [react-virtualized](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-virtualized).

Example codes:

```
const MenuList = props => {
  const rows = props.children;
  const rowRenderer = ({ key, index, isScrolling, isVisible, style }) => (
    <div key={key} style={style}>{rows[index]}</div>
  );

  return (
    <List
      style={{ width: '100%' }}
      width={300}
      height={300}
      rowHeight={30}
      rowCount={rows.length}
      rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
    />
  )
}
```

Inside render function

```
<Select
   components={{ MenuList }}
   defaultValue={this.state.options[10]}
   options={this.state.options}
 />
```

Comment: Do we have any example for Grouped Items for this
Ex : Group 1  with 1000 items under it and Group2 with 1000 items under it

I have found below one but not supporting multi select (isMulti)

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wing-5deq4?file=/src/index.jsx

Comment: How can I use it on Vite js?

Comment: I solved my own error. On vite js I have to import ```import { List } from 'react-virtualized/dist/commonjs/List';``` not ```import { List } from 'react-virtualized;```